# Windows IoT TcpListener or WCF/Web Service and Local Database

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2

I would like to use the Raspberry PI 2 and Windows on devices (or Windows IoT) to create a data logger.

The logger should be able to read sensors on the GPIO pins and store them on a local database. Then, on request, deliver the data either via a tcp connection or as a web/wcf service

My question is:

1. Can i create a SQL database on the Raspberry PI 2, running Windows 10 for devices.
2. is the TcpListener supported by the current Windows For Devices build (05/13/2015)
3. Is it possible to create a Web/WCF Service with the current build (05/13/2015)

Answer (score 4):

For the first of your questions is:

The best implementation is the following of SQLite, http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/

I have to say that implements a high level functionality as you do not need to use sql queries, you can work with the classes and LINQ directly.

about the rest of your questions there is a new implementation called AppService:

windows.appService

You have the example with all the details in here:

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/BlinkyWebServer.htm

All is new preview etc. Really exciting!